# Clunky and slow jQuery animation when using mobile browsers

Tags: jquery

Hi Im developing a site which uses .animate() and .slideToggle(), everything works fine in desktop browsers but at the time I test it in chrome or opera for android the animations get clunky and slow, I first though there was some performance issue but then I tried Firefox for android and realised it worked fast and great.

Can you guys give me any clue that can lead me to the solution of this problem?
I would appreciate anything that could help me.

Here is my code:

```
$("#respuestas, .responder").on("input", "textarea", function () {
  let inp = $(this);
   if(inp.val().length>1){
     inp.next(".form-section").find(".btn").removeClass("disabled");
   } else {
     inp.next(".form-section").find(".btn").addClass("disabled");
   }
 });

 $(".responder").on("click", ".res:not(.disabled)", function (evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   let elm = $(this).attr("id").split("-");
   let id = <?=$id?>;
   let txtArea=$("#contenido-" + id);
   let data = txtArea.serializeArray();
   data.push({name: "qid", value: id});
   $.ajax({
     method: "post",
     url: "../c/cqa.php",
     data: data,
     dataType: "json"
   }).done(function (response) {
     $.each(response, function (k, v){
       if (k==="status") {
         if (v==="ok") {
           txtArea.val("");
           $(".responder-" + id).click();
           let answerId = generateId();
           let seccionRespuestas = $("#respuestas");
           //respuestaDOM adds a div to the page
           respuestaDOM(response['name'], response['img'], response['url'], response['contenido'], seccionRespuestas , answerId);
           let answer = seccionRespuestas.find("#answer-" + answerId); 
           $("html, body").animate({
             'scrollTop': (answer.offset().top - 228)
           }, 500);
         }else{
           alert("Error."); //temporal alert
         }
       }
     });
   });
 });
```

**Thank you for your time**

Comment: Thanks @wp78de but that was not my case, even though at one point I tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I just tried my code on another post and I found it was fast in all android browsers I tested, the problem really was the size of the page, as I was loading 150+ records the page started to slow down and get clunky.

The solution is to create a pagination system when loading the records, sorry for the misunderstanding guys

**PD:** Something I learnt is that firefox handles well 'big' sites